# How restore a value without introducing external variables?

Tags: javascript, variables

Consider I want to temporarily set certain configuration property used by some other code to certain regretful value for a specific test and then restore the given original value. Is there some tricky way to make this less painful than this:

```js
var config = { a: 69 /*sane value here*/ }

let v = config.a //store the previous value

config.a = 66 //devil numbers I don't want in my life but for the sake of continuing my existence I'll do some evil

//test here with the above value

config.a = v //return to the previous value
```

I'm thinking of some invisible array I can push pop to (like stack?).

Comment: i would consider using an immutable data structure. https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/

Comment: You could prototype it is if that's an option.

Comment: `config._backup = {}; config._backup.a = config.a; config.a=66; config.a=config._backup.a;` no external variables